# Possible Error in the 1990 B1 Putnam Answer Key

Tags: integration, contest-math

Find all real differentiable functions $f$ that satisfy the following.

$$f(a)^2 = \int_0^a (f(x)^2 + f'(x)^2)dx + 1990 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$

The solution manual is found [here](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol907.html).

> Putting $y = f(x)$ and differentiating the relationship gives $2y y' = y^2 + y'^2$ or $(y - y')^2 = 0$. So $y = y'$ or $y = -y'$. Integrating, $y = Ae^x$ or $y = - Ae^x$. But $y(0) = \pm \sqrt{1990}$, so $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{1990}e^x$.

Wouldn't the differential linear differential equation $y'=-y$ yield a solution of $y=Ae^{-x}$ as opposed to $y=-Ae^x$? Additionally, I am unsure why the solution $y=-y'$ is even necessary.

Comment: Good questions (+1)

Comment: I don't think that solutions page is from a publication of the MAA. It appears to be the work of one author, so some mistakes could be expected.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Left side is a function of $x$, whilst the right side is a function of $a$.

Comment: yes, @user58697, in the link the left side is $f(a)^2$

Comment: Thank you, I'll correct my typo. Guess I'm a bit of a hypocrite, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is correct, but you only get $y'=y$ (which follows from $(y'-y)^2=0$), hence $y=Ce^x$ and, setting $a=0$, $y=\pm\sqrt{1990}e^x$